# inline __declspec(naked) function within a class

Tags: c++, hook

I'm working on refactoring a hook into a class to get rid of global variables etc. However I'm struggling a bit with [`inline __declspec(naked)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/naked-cpp?view=msvc-170). I want to have this within my class so I could access my members within the inline assembly. I'm using ICC compiler so this should work for x64 and does when I use globals.

Hooks.hpp

```cpp
class EntityHook
{
public:
    EntityHook(std::vector<Entity*>& entVector);
    ~EntityHook();

private:
    std::vector<Entity*>* m_entities;

    std::unique_ptr<Hook> m_entHook;
    DWORD64 m_returnAddy;
    int m_hookSize = 17;
    Entity* m_ent;

    inline __declspec(naked) void entity_hook_h()
    {
        __asm {
            pop rax;
        }
        __asm {
            mov[m_ent], rdi
            movss xmm7, [rdi + 0x54]
            movss xmm8, [rdi + 0x58]
            movss xmm9, [rdi + 0x5C]
        }
...
```

Hooks.cpp

```cpp
#include "Hooks.h"

EntityHook::EntityHook(std::vector<Entity*>& entVector)
{
    m_entities = &entVector;
    m_entities->resize(255);

    DWORD64 entList = HelperFunctions::PatternScan(PROCESS, signatures::sharedEnt);
    m_returnAddy = entList + m_hookSize;
    m_entHook = std::make_unique<Hook>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(entList), reinterpret_cast<void*>(entity_hook_h), m_hookSize);
}
```

This works perfectly fine if I move the function to outside the class and replace the members with globals.

Comment: I accidentally linked to the MSVC version of `__decltype(naked)` which states that it doesn't work for x64. Can you replace it with a link to the ICC version? I couldn't find it.

Comment: ICC is different compiler. Not sure what you mean by link to ICC version. You mean a link to where to download the compiler?

Comment: No, I was thinking of linking to the ICC manual page where people can read about `__decltype(naked)`. The link I put into your question goes to the MSVC description of `__decltype(naked)` and there it says that it's not available for x86 - so ICC must have a different description? Where did you read about it and that it supports x64?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I don't know. I don't really use Intels compiler because I never find what I'm looking for. But it works exactly like it does for MSVC in x86.

Comment: Yes, but you mention `x64` and MSVC says that it's not supported.

Comment: Works fine in ICC (Intel C++ Compiler 19.2).

Comment: ...which is why I hoped for a link to the ICC documentation for `__decltype(naked)` :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245467/discussion-between-megamagnum-and-ted-lyngmo).